# Set position of TableView on screen

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm trying to set the position of a table view on the screen, i tried to do it on IB but it doesn't seem to be working is there a way to do it programmatically or am i missing something in IB i set the X and Y on the view part it shows the table view moving but it doesn't work when i run the app.

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: can you add the link of image of xib here, might be issue with auto resizing?

Comment: Yes i'm using UITableViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `UITableViewController` then you will not be able to change the position of the `UITableView` since the main view of your application will be a `UITableView`

Instead you will have to change the class of the `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`
Then in the xib file, Drop a `UITableView` inside the main view, and change the x and y
This way it should work

Comment: Hello just a quick question, for some reason when i click on a cell it takes me to the next view no problem with that but when i come back for some reason it stays highlighted i still have the blue thin on the cell it doesn't resume to normal state any idea what could cause that?

Comment: in didSelectCell... add the following     [tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Comment: you got it just one last thing do you know if i can change the color of the selection don't want to use the blue one if possible

Comment: sure, in cellForRow.. write the following cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

you can choose one of UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray, UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue and UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone